# Material preview and rendered viewport show completely different shading

Tags: materials

I am currently coloring a procedural monster I made and have realized I have two very different results in my material preview and rendered viewport:

Material preview:
[image]

Rendered:
[image]

I don't think this kind of difference is the result of HRDI lighting, does anyone have any leads?
The purple material I am using is the most basic kind, just principle BSDF with the base color set as purple, all other settings are default. Thanks so much!!

[image]

Comment: Are you using Cycles for the rendered result? Material Preview uses Eevee so it's possible you're seeing the difference between the two renderers although I'm not familiar with differences which could cause that.

Comment: Some nodes don't work in Eevee, so it indeed might be the difference between Eevee and cycles.